# Symfony2 Container merge/add parameters to the specific key

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Container:

```
$newContainer = new ContainerBuilder();
```

I load some parameters:

```
$loader = new YamlFileLoader($newContainer, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config/newFolder'));
$loader->load('newParameters.yml');
```

And my container looks like this:

```
  [parameters:protected] => Array
        (
            [exampleKey => Array
                (
                    [parameter] => something value
                    [anotherParameter] => another value
                )

        )
```

Now i do the merge:

```
$container->merge($newContainer);
```

And my merge looks like this - print_r($container):

```
  [parameters:protected] => Array
        (
            [existing] => Array
                (
                ...
                )
            [existing2] => Array
                (
                ...
                )          
            [exampleKey => Array
                (
                    [parameter] => something value
                    [anotherParameter] => another value
                )
            [existing3] => Array
                (
                ...
                )    
        )
```

**How can merge my container so i have this??:**

```
  [parameters:protected] => Array
        (
            [existing] => Array
                (
                ...
                )
            [existing2] => Array
                (
                ...
                [exampleKey => Array
                    (
                        [parameter] => something value
                        [anotherParameter] => another value
                    )                    
                )          
            [existing3] => Array
                (
                ...
                )    
        )
```

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use merge, use add():

```
$container->getParameterBag()
          ->add(array(
              'existing2' => $newContainer->getParameterBag()->all()
          ));
```

I didnt know there are methods hidden after $container->getParameterBag(), you can use: ->all(), set(), has(), get() etc. Very useful. Thanks